# which code is better?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I suggested my senior to use hashmap insted of below code for matching the data. I am sure the complexity of the below code is O(n*n), I think with hashing this can be linear. can anyone of you verify whether I am right ? assume presencePatients = 100000,fhirPatients = 10000,beds = 10000 and departments= 5000

```
let filteredPatients = new Array();

presencePatient.forEach( patient => {

    let fhir  = fhirPatient.find((fhir)=>{
        return ( fhir.pid === patient.id);
    });

    let beds = bedsInHospital.find( (bed) => {
        return (bed.id === patient.bedId);
    });

    let deparmtment = departmentsInHospital.find( (deparmtment) => {
        return (deparmtment.id === patient.icuId);
    });

    let obj = {
        name : patient.name,
        dob : patient.dateOfBirth,
        gender : patient.gender,
        email : patient.emailId,
        maritialStatus : patient.maritialStatus,
        mrn : patient.mrn,
        contact : patient.phoneNumber,
        bed : beds.name,
        deparmtment : deparmtment.name
    };

    filteredPatients.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: What is the code you are suggesting ?

Comment: It largely depends on the data. The overhead of settings up some kind of lookup may not be desirable in some cases. I'm willing to bet it doesn't matter much unless you're running this over a huge dataset. Also, why not use `map()`

Comment: Code reviews should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - that's the reason your question will be downvoted by many folks (not me - I'm not bashing newbies).

Comment: @Hexodus OP has been a member over a year, should know the rules by now - not a noob but surely if you are asking if one version is better than another, you should post both versions?

Comment: @Pete You're right but I judged strictly by his reputation...

Comment: @Hexaodus will keep in mind next time , btw thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @ Evan Trimboli , yes it's a huge dataset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Better" is a subjective term.

Some points to consider:

- Yes, if you had a `Map` or an object keyed by `id` for patients, beds, and departments, in general looking up patients, beds, and departments by `id` would be faster using that `Map`/object instead of a linear searches of those arrays.
- **But**, presuming that you need the arrays as well for other parts of your code, maintaining both an array and a `Map`/object incurs costs of code complexity (the main issue) and additional overhead.
- A linear search will only be problematic if the arrays are large.

**If** there's a performance problem with the code listed, then you might consider `Map`/object lookup (accepting the costs of adding it in favor of increased speed). But if there isn't, it may be premature optimization introducing unnecessary code complexity.

Comment: thanks for the reply, It's a huge data set with more than 100000 data of patients.

Comment: Ohh, its T.J's answer, lets up-vote it even before reading :)

Comment: @MohammadUsman: **:-)** Please don't though, I get things wrong far too frequently. Fortunately people let me know (with comments and/or votes) so I can fix it.

Comment: @shashikantdwivedi Thats 100 000 patients * X fhirPatients * Y beds * Z departments. It would be good to add it to your question (and provide some rough estimates for X/Y/Z values too)

Comment: okay will do that, and I agree it is little ill phrased.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I'll try but I won't make a promise :)

Comment: Ups. My estimate of number of operation is wrong it should be: 100 000 * (X fhirPatients + Y beds + Z departments), as those extra joins are unrelated to each other.

Comment: why so many down votes ? @T.J Crowder

Answer (score 2):

There is good answer by @T.J. Crowder. However I would like to put forward my dissenting opinion on upper bound of usefulness of indexing data structures.

Yes. It may be true that source data is used and modified in multiple places apart from above code. It may be true that updating indexing auxiliary structures could provide extra performance benefits. But it would entail extra complexity to the code elsewhere, that may not be acceptable trade off for this application.

However, I would like to point out that above code will do:
100 000 * (X fhirPatients + Y beds + Z departments) iterations in various loops.

If on the other hand we do indexing pass it would be roughly equivalent to:
6 * (X fhirPatients + Y beds + Z departments)

That's very cheap cost to build indexes, and as such, **even if done only for above code, it would speed it up significantly!**

Second point that need to be brought up, is that for large compute heavy code, efficient data structure should be used as primary ones. So maybe refactoring from arrays to hashmaps is good decision. If data usage is even more complex, introduction of light or full in-memory and in-process db would also help keep complexity in check.

Comment: *"There is good answer by @T.J. Crowder. However I would like to put forward my dissenting opinion..."* My answer doesn't say you shouldn't use indexing structures. I outline costs and flag up that if speed is a known concern, using them would help.

Comment: Hopefully my answer give some tips, on how to tackle indexing when usage patterns are more complex. That's why I add "upper bound" there ;)

Comment: Hopefully, yes. Your point about even if you have to build the index each time will be true, or not, depending on which "patients" the OP was talking about with that figure (`presentPatients` or `fhirPatients`) and the other values. Sadly, he/she hasn't filled us in on them. :-)

Comment: Hmm. Right if (X + Y +Z) is small, it shouldn't help.